# Data retrieval failed with subreport CRM SSRS report error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have a report in Microsoft CRM 8.2 on premise that goes into a timeout after 60s - report cannot be displayed error and "Data retrieval failed for the SubReport1" in the SSRS logs.

This report was running on CRM 2015 without any issues - the problem occured after the upgrade.

The report is running in report server as well as in report builder without any issues, it is also running in CRM but with records that the processing is done under 60s.

I changed all the necessary settings refered to other posts regarding timeouts but the issue persists.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

PS. report is using SPs and it is a subreport with no shared datasets - I also tried running the parent report separately without issues, so I guess the issue is with the subreport.

modified web.config of CRM, modified the rsreportserver.config, modified reporting services site settings, even modified the registry (OLEDBTimeout, ExtendedTimeout) values.

Comment: The subreport runs fine on it's own? Are you sure the parameters are passed correctly when called from the parent report?

Comment: it is not running fine on it's own, it is failing after 60s - parameters are passed correctly, I created a simple SP with just a select statement and a new report using that SP. I added a delay to the SP for 2 mins and I am still getting the issue, if I set the delay to 1 min it is running just fine...

Comment: have you had a look at parameter sniffing? could possibly be an avenue to see if this is what is pausinbly causing the delay in the report being rendered. I'm not sure what the dealy you added to the sp would achieve??